# Automatically insertion of 00 in EIP in Stack Overflow 64bit

Tags: shellcode, stack-overflow

I am trying to overflow a stack in C sample code to execute uncalled function in code.

The problem is when i overflow stack by entering a(24 times), $EIP is 0x555555550061. I want it to be 0x555555555561. Why these two zeros are inserted automatically?

I retrieved this values from gdb. For Instance, if that uncalled function address is 0x555555555561, I can not call that function because of these zeros.

I tried using:

`./(name of executable) $(cat input.txt)    #input.txt has input string 24 times a with no '\n'`

but same problem.

I am running 5.5.0-kali2-amd64.

Comment: Maybe there's an instruction that modifies the value at that address?

Comment: It's works correctly in other pc with same code.

Answer (score 0):

The null byte is almost certainly from the end of your a filled string. if you're not trying for a partial overwrite the more common approach would be to send more characters and overwrite all of EIP with 0x61616161.... You can then alter the overwrite bytes to any value you want, including 0x555555555561.

Comment: But Whats reason behind this? It works correctly in other computer with ubuntu. And, I cant overwrite rest of values because address of function is approx in last 2 bytes rest is just assigned by computer itself. For Instance 555555.